# "URI has an authority component" when resolving URI

Tags: .net, xslt, uri, saxon

I am getting the "`URI has an authority component`" error when trying to create a document during an XSLT transformation on a network location.

The transformation works fine locally on my pc.

My original template was:

```
<xsl:template match="map">
        <xsl:variable name="model" select="translate(@product,' ','')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="documentType" select="lower-case(@platform)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="locale" select="lower-case(translate(@audience,'-','_'))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="directory"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(base-uri(/),'/toc.ditamap')"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="bookName" select="concat($documentType,'_',$model,'_info_',$locale,'.xml')"/>
        
        <xsl:result-document href="{$directory}/{$bookName}">
            <info>
                <xsl:for-each select="//topicref">
                    <xsl:variable name="topicFileName" select="@href"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="enterMetadata">
                        <xsl:with-param name="topicFileName" select="$directory/$topicFileName"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </info>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
```

But the URI in `xsl:result-document` was (wrongly) resolved as follows:

```
file:/C:/[somepath]/DITA/Operator%20Manual/om_CSUV_info_en_us.xml
```

So I changed the template to this (I am aware that string substitutions are not a good approach, but I am trying to get at least some output):

```
<xsl:template match="map">
        <xsl:variable name="model" select="translate(@product,' ','')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="documentType" select="lower-case(@platform)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="locale" select="lower-case(translate(@audience,'-','_'))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="directory"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(replace(base-uri(/),'file:/C:/','file:/'),'/toc.ditamap')"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="bookName" select="concat($documentType,'_',$model,'_info_',$locale,'.xml')"/>
        
        <xsl:result-document href="{$directory}/{$bookName}">
            <info>
                <xsl:for-each select="//topicref">
                    <xsl:variable name="topicFileName" select="@href"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="enterMetadata">
                        <xsl:with-param name="topicFileName" select="$directory/$topicFileName"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </info>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
```

Now I am getting the following error:

```
Error in xsl:result-document/@href on line 30 column 62 of metadata.xsl:

  Cannot write to URI

  file://[somepath]/Publishing/DITA/Operator%20Manual/om_CSUV_info_en_us.xml (URI has an authority component)


  in built-in template rule


Cannot write to URI file://[somepath]/Publishing/DITA/Operator%20Manual/om_CSUV_info_en_us.xml (URI has an authority component)
```

This same problem was debated at length here https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4280, but it is still not clear to me what to do to get it working. I am not a programmer, I just write XSLT scripts.

I am using Saxon HE 9.7 .Net.

Comment: Well, if you think it is the issue in the linked bug entry then try a release after the fix e.g. PE 9.9.1.5 or later. On the other hand, that issue seems to be about an EXPath function, are you using that at all? It would help if you spelled out the URI that causes the error, it might be important to know what `[somepath]` really stands for. Do you want to write to a local file on the local disk e.g. the `C:` drive under Windows or are you trying to use UNC to write to another server on the local network?

Comment: I asked our Operations team if we can use PE 9.9. In the meanwhile, I have to try to solve it with 9.7 HE.
I wrote [somepath] to hide sensitive info. it would be like: 
file://xxx-eu1c1smb/clients$/xxx-eu1c1/1/B/CustomerNAME/Users/customername.ASuppor/Publishing/DITA/Operator%20Manual/
I am not using that function specifically, but from what I understand, this is a general problem in URI resolution across different languages.
I do my tests on C:, and there the script works. If I try to write to a network location, I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk of a "network location", does that mean you are using a UNC filename such as `//server/path`? There's a long-standing problem that there's no consensus on how such filenames should be represented as URIs, and in particular, Java and .NET do it differently. Because Saxon 9.x on .NET involves both Java code and .NET code, it becomes particularly problematic.

The Wikipedia article on the `file URI scheme` sums up the muddle quite well:

> There are two ways that Windows UNC filenames (such as
> \server\folder\data.xml) can be represented. These are both described
> in RFC 8089, Appendix E as "non-standard". The first way (called here
> the 2-slash format) is to represent the server name using the
> Authority part of the URI, which then becomes
> file://server/folder/data.xml. The second way (called here the 4-slash
> format) is to represent the server name as part of the Path component,
> so the URI becomes file:////server/folder/data.xml. Both forms are
> actively used. Microsoft .NET (for example, the method new Uri(path))
> generally uses the 2-slash form; Java (for example, the method new
> URI(path)) generally uses the 4-slash form. Either form allows the
> most common operations on URIs (resolving relative URIs, and
> dereferencing to obtain a connection to the remote file) to be used
> successfully. However, because these URIs are non-standard, some less
> common operations fail: an example is the normalize operation (defined
> in RFC 3986 and implemented in the Java java.net.URI.normalize()
> method) which reduces file:////server/folder/data.xml to the unusable
> form file:/server/folder/data.xml.[5]

Comment: The transformation happens on a location with a UNC filename like file://xxx-eu1c1smb/clients$/xxx-eu1c1/1/B/CustomerNAME/Users/customername.ASuppor/Publishing/DITA/Operator%20Manual/.
No matter how many slashes I add here, it still gets resolved to two (file://xxx- etc.):

<xsl:variable name="directory"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(replace(base-uri(/),'file:/C:/','file:/'),'/toc.ditamap')"/></xsl:variable>

Comment: As you can see from the discussion on bug issue 4285, we did a lot of work on this in the Saxon 9.9 timeframe. I'm sorry, but I can't give you any more help on a Saxon 9.7 issue.

Comment: Does that mean that upgrading to 9.9 should fix it? And if so, only PE or HE as well?

Comment: I don't know without trying it. It might be the same problem, it might not. But if you move to a supported release (11.3 is the latest) then you can legitimately ask Saxonica for help.

Comment: A final comment that can maybe be useful to others: I upgraded to 9.9 and then 10, the Java as well as .Net version, but was still getting the same error. I eventually rewrote the script to pass the path as a parameter, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to a network location which is already mapped to a path on your local file system you should probably use a `file:` URI with an explicitly empty authority component, e.g. `file:///c%3A/blah/blah/blah.xml`